# JOIN in two Dictionary views

Tags: sql, oracle, dictionary

I have difficulties with completing this task from a workshop and can't find right answer anywhere.

> By using join between two dictionary views display file name, number
>   of extents and total number of blocks for user DAVE and his tables EMP
>   and BIG_EMP.

I know that extents are in DBA_SEGMENTS view and BLOCKS are in ALL_TABLES. But what is file name and how I do query for user and for user tables?

Comment: Are you referring to the tablespace datafile name? All users are in all_users and tables are in all_tables. Check the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/tahiti/tahiti.catalog_views).

Comment: @ruudvan I guess so. But it says join two dictionary views.

Comment: well, datafiles for the tablespace are in dba_data_files but the question is still not clear as to what you are asking. The datafiles won't tell you which file has which objects in it. Just the blocks in a tablespace